# How to add custom column labels to CSV written by pandas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a simple 3 column numpy data which i am planning to write to CSV using pandas

```
X = ([[ 0.63929417,  0.71804657,  0.62530184],
       [ 0.91736598,  0.42696823,  0.36432443],
       [ 0.34529593,  0.98629196,  0.19780149],
       [ 0.24696517,  0.62660763,  0.25418833],
       [ 0.63404232,  0.70276032,  0.88243513],
       [ 0.40073419,  0.93373199,  0.28116287],
       [ 0.43908317,  0.66116296,  0.33441886],
       [ 0.62667038,  0.88563705,  0.33575855],
       [ 0.24745741,  0.35070823,  0.59614696],
       [ 0.50416922,  0.79734483,  0.48907875]])
```

Both of the last 2 lines doesnt seem to write the column labels in the CSV.

```
df = pd.Dataframe(X.values)
df.to_csv('test.csv', cols=['First','Second','Third'])
df.to_csv('test.csv',header=['First','Second','Third'])
```

Comment: Your last option (using the `header` keyword) does work for me.

Comment: What version of pandas do you have?

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the columns names before writing you df:

```
df = pd.Dataframe(X.values)
df.columns = ['First','Second','Third']
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

`cols` is depracated, and replace by `columns`, and allows you to choose the columns to write.
`header` is either True or False and let you choose to write the header (ie columns names) or not. [edit: It actually works too as joris just said, maybe not in your version of pandas]

edit2: Your second solution should work if you have pandas 0.8.0 or more.

[Version 0.7.0 doesn't have that option](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.7.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: This is not fully true. You can indeed set the columns names before writing to csv, but you can also overwrite the current columns names using the `header` keyword. When giving a list to `header`, this will be interpreted as new column names to use, see the docstring: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version you are using but the following works in latest version:

```
df.to_csv(r'c:\data\sample.csv', header=['First','Second','Third'])
```

`cols` param selects the columns that already exist so that won't work see the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv

from the docs:

> columns : sequence, optional Columns to write
>
> header : boolean or list of string, default True Write out column
>   names. If a list of string is given it is assumed to be aliases for
>   the column names